# Why priority_queue doesn't have front() but top()

Tags: c++, stl

Since it's a 'queue', shouldn't the method be called `front()` rather than `top()` ? Is there some reason behind this?

Comment: A `priority_queue` is not a `queue`.

Comment: It is misnamed, just like every other method in the STL collections.

Comment: It's probably an override and so you're stuck with the name from the customizable parent class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because (in my estimation - as I didn't name it..) they're commonly implemented with heaps which conceptually have a top - as in stuff rises to the top of the heap to be taken off next.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue